# Normal map on only part of the material

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying to apply a normal map on a plane with two textures painted on it,
but in a way that it's only applied to the second one. It's a really simple 
scene of a crossroad going through a field (for testing the normal map).

The thing is that I can't figure out how to apply the normal map so that
it uses only the road texture and not the whole plane. I have done my researches 
about this problem with no luck, so I'd really appreciate any help.

Not sure if I'm using correct terms to describe this but here's a figure and
link to the .blend file to give you a better idea what I mean.

.blend: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4NHszZHPR_1TFlfdThBMjF6MzA&usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of things I changed with your file, so here's my edited version: [Edited .blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2YsjX3U74sedUNQc3U3VGp5VjQ/view?usp=sharing)

First off there were a few things you did wrong with your normal map:

- When using an image for the normal map you have to set the Texture node to non-color data mode.
- Then, you don't plug the image texture into the Displacement input of the material node(only takes B/W data), but instead into the Normal input of your respective shader.

Now that we've covered that it becomes very easy to achieve what you want:

You plug the normal map only into your pebble shader, so that only the pebbles get bump mapping effects, and the mask you already created does the rest. For that I added a second vector input to you group nodes so that they can receive normal mapping data as well.

Also, if you are using only one UV map, a single UV map node is usually enough.

Comment: It's working now as I wanted it to. At first I thought it still wasn't working, but I made the original texture little more hi-res and added some extra strength to the bump effect. Now I can get back to Blender without any frustration. Thanks!